# Where can I find the template of the Model that is generated by the scaffolder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, code-generation

I want to costumize the `Model` generator/scaffolder that is used by rails e.g.:

```
rails generate model ModelName field:field_tyle,...
rails generate scaffold ModelName field:field_type,...
```

to pretend some areas and it should look like this when Im done cosutumizing the template.

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
     # ASSOCIATIONS

     # VALIDATIONS

     # ATTR RELATED STUFF

     # INSTANCE METHODS

     # CLASS METHODS
end
```

instead of:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

It was easy to find the `View` Templates used by the scaffolder but its not that easy to find the template for the Model. Where can I find it or is there "only" a generator for this and when how can I costumize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a guide on customizing rails generators [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html). File location you can check at [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org%20you) just need to know class name also you can check [nifty generators](https://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators) by Ryan Bates

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue it took some doing but this work for me.

The ActiveRecord model generator templates for Rails 3.1 go in:
**lib/templates/active_record/model/**
This could be either **model.rb, migration.rb or module.rb**

I imagine that DataMapper or MongoMapper go in analogous locations.  Hope this helps.